# Undefined variable $menus in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a menu and in this menu items come from Categories

For the test, I create a new section called Menu for this menu to create the menu manually.

But after that, I return all codes to the previous version, But still, I have an error for undefined $menus

But I don't have this menu anywhere, where is the problem?

**Error**

```
Undefined variable $menus (View: 
C:\Web\projects\thermotajhiz\resources\views\layouts\header.blade.php)
```

**View**

```
<ul class="list-menu-level-2">
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                    @if($category->menu == 1)
                        <li class="item-menu-2">
                            <a href="#" class="list-category-menu-2" rel="nofollow">
                                <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
                                {{ $category->name }}
                            </a>
                            <ul class="megamenu-level-3" style="display:block;">
                                @include('layouts.categories-group',['categories' => $category- 
                                >get_sub($category->id)])
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </ul>
```

**Controller**

```
$categories = Category::with('child')->where('parent_id', 0)->get();
return view('index', compact('categories'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run a command `php artisan view:clear`, because laravel makes a cache for every view file. after runnig this command, all compiled views should clear and rebuild cache for view for present file.